# Powershell Office 365 create set of test users with appended environments but same domain

Tags: email, powershell

Basically I'm playing with `get-content` to create a bunch of users in Office365:

```
$a=get-content C:\users.txt
foreach($b in $a)
{New-Mailbox -Name $b -Alias $b –Shared -PrimarySmtpAddress $b@email.org
Add-MailboxPermission $b -User me@email.com -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $true}
```

This works to bulk import a set of users from a text file, but I need to take it a step further.

I have 2 users in `users.txt`:

```
user1
user2
```

I have 4 different test stacks in `stacks.txt`:

```
uat1
qa1
trn1
cln1
```

I want a total of 8 users maybe in a text file or as results that I can variable into the script above:

```
user1uat
user1qa1
user1trn1
user1cln1
user2uat
user2qa1
user2trn1
user2clan1
```

Not sure how to accomplish this in a way that I can set it as a variable to then created 8 shared mailboxes using the script above.

Comment: In SQL it would be a cross join, not sure if there is a reflection in Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Think i figured it out.

```
$a=get-content C:\irusers.txt
$c=get-content C:\stacks.txt
$e=foreach ($b in $a) {
    foreach ($d in $c) {
    -join($b,$d)}}
```